# CLI upload main.js file size limited when building with react and threejs

Tags: reactjs, hubspot-cms

Is there a way around the file size limitation when building with react and threejs? I am building a react module with three js using the cms-react-boilerplate. The project builds fine, but it can't upload the main.js file as it is 2.1MiB. It gives me the following error:

> [ERROR] Error validating template.
> [ERROR] line 0: Coded files must be smaller than 1.5 MiB

I tried to upload the file directly to the design manager but was given the same error.
I also tried to create a main.js file and paste the code into it, but was given the following error:

> Error:Coded file buffer must be smaller than 2.0 MiB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend enabling code splitting. If not, you're going to need to use a different host for the JavaScript files. Additionally – make sure you're correctly including only what you need.

Avoid:

```
import * as x from 'lib';
```

and instead do:

```
import { each, func, you, need } from 'lib';
```

This will allow bundlers such as Webpack to properly Tree Shake your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try compressing your files into .min.js files [with this](https://www.toptal.com/developers/javascript-minifier/) if you are done editing them.